# golang http handle big file upload

Tags: html, file-upload, webserver, go

I'm using the golang `net/http` package to construct a webserver.And now I have to handle big file upload which means that the server may get request with `Expect: 100 Continue`.I will not send response to the client until all data has been received.However every time I finished one request and return, the golang will send a response back by default,How can i implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but the `net/http` server in Go should handle `Expect` requests properly. Have a look at http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L1072 and http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/serve_test.go#L741 for more info.

Comment: @Intermernet Thank you!well,yes I'v read that before,It handles the 100 Continues seems just tells the client the server supports it and request to send more data.While  my problem is that how can i accumulate all data from many successive data part of one request and handle it then send response back.

Comment: are you using multipart/form-data to upload the file? If so, try `Request.MultipartReader`(http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader) to read the request data as a stream.

Comment: @Intermernet No...I use the pure HTTP body to carry data(Neither chunk nor others).So I wonder if my way is the standard way to upload big file data?

Comment: May or may not be helpful but the "standard" way to upload big file data is via SFTP.

Comment: @cheneydeng Use `Request.MultipartReader` like Intermernet says, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: there must be something wrong with your client.

Comment: @Intermernet I think you are correct.. You should write that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use request.ParseMultipartForm,

> ParseMultipartForm parses a request body as multipart/form-data. The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on disk in temporary files. ParseMultipartForm calls ParseForm if necessary. After one call to ParseMultipartForm, subsequent calls have no effect.

```
So yo just can do:

    import(
       "ioutil"
       "net/http"
    )
//check all posible errors, I´m assuming you just have one file per key
    func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.ParseMultipartForm(1000000) //1 MB in memory, the rest in disk
        datas := r.MultipartForm
        for k, headers := range datas.File {
            auxiliar, _ := headers[0].Open() //first check len(headers) is correct
            fileName:=headers[0].Filename
            file, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(auxiliar)
            // do what you need to do with the file
    }
}
```

at the frontEnd you should have some javascript like this:

```js
function handleFile(url,file){
  let data=new FormData();
  data.append("key",file); //this is the key when ranging over map at backEnd
  fetch(url,{method:"PUT",body:data})
}
```

Comment: As of Go 1.16 `ioutil` is deprecated. See https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil for the mapping with new functions in `io` and `os`. Specifically here, `ioutil.ReadAll` becomes `io.ReadAll`